# Animated old version of the Fire Bird?

Tags: story-identification

Another question for old fogies with good memories. Back in the early 60's or late 50's I saw part of an animated version of the Russian Fire Bird tale on the Early Show. The scene I saw was of the hero chasing the Fire Bird around a forest with a wooden tub, trying to capture it.
The cartoon had to be done in the early 50's or very late 40's. Does anyone know what I saw?

Answer (score 11):

You're looking for the Humpbacked Horse aka The Magic Pony in the States. An animated film from the Soviet Union, made in 1947. Ivan, the youngest of three sons catches a magical flying horse, who has been taking hay from their fields. The Horse convinces Ivan to let her go and gives him a humpbacked pony. The Tsar commands Ivan, to catch a Firebird for him. Which he does, but I don't remember the specific scene you're asking about. The next task is catch a beautiful maid for him. The maid tells the Tsar, she will only marry him, if he becomes young and handsome. He needs to do this by jumping into a tub of boiling water, then a tub of milk and the a tub of freezing water. The Tsar's Advisor tell the Tsar that Ivan should do it first. Through the magic of the Humpbacked Pony, Ivan survives the tubs and is transformed from a boy into a handsome man.  The movie is on YouTube as The Little Humpbacked Horse.

[image]

Here's the scene you may have been thinking of. However, the tub is being used to put food in to lure the firebird and for the MC to hide under till it comes close.
[Tub scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BS1OIiRY1MM&start=1626&end=1712)